# Not understanding how to implement WPF navigation task C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a task for an assessment and I am don't understand how to implement it in code. I think I need an `if` statement to decide which instance of a page I need to navigate to but not sure how to pass the `Person` object to the that even with the TIP saying I can access it with the RoutedEventArgs. Anyone can help with this?

This is what I have got so far:

```
 public partial class Index : Page
    {
        private Repository _repo;
        public Index(Repository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
            InitializeComponent();

            //TODO: (Task 6A) 
            //assign the collection of People objects return from the repository
            //as the data source for the DataGrid (dgPeople)

            var source = _repo.GetPeople();
            dgPeople.ItemsSource = source;

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            //TODO: (Task 6B) 
            //add the required logic for instantiating and navigating to a new instance of the Edit or Delete view.
            //Be sure to pass in the selected Person object and repository as arguments for the constructor.
            //TIP: the related Person instance can be accessed via the RoutedEventArgs 

            //edit or delete
            string action = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
            Person p = new Person();

            Delete delete = new Delete(_repo, p);
            Update edit = new Update(_repo, p);

        }    
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that Person will be the DataContext of the button that fired the event.

Comment: I have a class of person and then a class of repository which is populated by the Person. I am not understanding a lot of how this works to br honest. And what's the difference between datacontext and itemsource

Comment: Who give you an assignment? Why not asking him?

Comment: I only have one class a week with who gave me the assignment and i am trying to get help understanding this. Thanks for your question @sinatr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create a new `Person` instance in the event handler `Button_Click`. Otherwise the clicked `Person` and edited/deleted instance will be different and changes won't be reflected in the GUI.
Following the instructions that guide you very clearly, you have to access the event args parameter `e` of the event handler to get the source of the event (the `Person`):

```
var clickedPerson = e.OriginalSource as Person;
```

or alternatively:

```
var clickedPerson = e.Source as Person;
```

Whether to use `e.OriginalSource` or `e.Source` depends on how your view is setup. You have to try both or use the debugger to see the actual values of both properties.

Now that you have the correct `Person` instance, you have to check which view to load.  From the context you have posted, it is not possible to know the exact conditions. But yes, an `if` can test this condition and branch accordingly.

It's also not clear how your page system is setup e.g., are you using `Frame`? In this case you have to use the `Page.NavigationService` in order to be able to load the new view:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(edit);
```

It's always useful and recommended to search the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/) and [.NET API browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=net-5.0) to learn more about the framework and specific classes and their properties. For example to learn about `DataContext` visit [`FrameworkElement.DataContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=net-5.0#remarks)

Comment: Thanks for the help man, this clears up a lot for me  Will give the docs a read as well, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I'm guessing a lot of this since I can't see how your view is set up.

You have a `DataGrid` called `dgPeople`. This is just a generic control for showing collections of things.

You set the `ItemsSource` of `dgPeople` to your collection of People. So your `DataGrid` is now showing a collection of people objects.

Every view item in WPF has a `DataContext`. This is the data that the view item is based on / looking at. Each row in your DataGrid corresponds to a single Person, so everything in that row will automatically have its DataContext set to that Person.

You can access the DataContext of any view element using the [DataContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=net-5.0) property, so you can access it via the Button that fired the event.

Comment: That actually made a lot of sense @GazTheDestroyer. It clears the datacontext part for me. Now i need to understand how to do the rest